# Как водить только буквы в QLineEdit?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qlineedit

Как сделать так, что бы можно было вводить только буквы в `lineEdit`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> void QLineEdit::**setValidator**(const QValidator *v)
>
> Устанавливает валидатор для значений редактирования строки на v.

Больше https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#setValidator

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets, QtCore

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.lineEdit= QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        
        rx  = QtCore.QRegExp("[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я .,]{100}")    
        val = QtGui.QRegExpValidator(rx)                 
        self.lineEdit.setValidator(val)                   
        self.setCentralWidget(self.lineEdit)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]